# Use Oracle users to provide access to asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle

I am creating a asp.net web application. The access to the application will be based on username and password. Users are created in Oracle (not stored on my database).

Is it possible to use Oracle users to provide access to my web application?

I know how to connect to Oracle database using admin user in .NET. I want to use users, created in Oracle, to provide access to my web application.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought from a newbie... Can you make an Oracle connection attempt, and deny login on error? If it doesn't fail, it means the database connection went well so you could accept the login for that user.

Comment: It's a good idea.. but just wondering if too many wrong attempts will lead to lock database?